# Using microMIPS along with other ISA

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, embedded, mips

I am compiling a RTOS + applications for an embedded device.

I was recently introduced with the microMIPS (-mmicromips) and the interlinking (-minterlink-compressed) option for GCC and I got confused about it.

1. From what i understand - micromips architecture is used to "shrink" commands and reduce the size of the resulting binary image. is this correct? are there other benefits of using this option? ([source](https://doc.lagout.org/electronics/doc/mips/architecture/MD00784-2B-umicroMIPS-APP-01.00.pdf))
2. What is the second option (interlink-compressed) used for?
3. When I try to call a function that is inside a compilation unit that was compiled with microMIPS (with or without interlink-compressed) flag in GCC from a compilation unit that was flagged with non-microMIPS - i get an error, stating its an "unsupported jump between ISA modes". the solution seems to be either one of:

   - compiling with interlinking enabled (suggested by the compiler)
   - use "a call or an indirect jump" (from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html))

Since im not sure what the interlink flags do, im not sure if the first option suits my needs. as for the second one - how can i force such indirect jump from C code?

Thanks

Comment: From the compiler docs, it looks like you should compile everything with -minterlink-compressed.

Comment: @markgz which docs are you referring to?